# Failed to compile react project

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a React project and I am redesigning and optimizing the code. The thing is I had in layout a file named "Footer.js". I want to erase it, but when I erase it or I change the name, the project doesnt compile and it appears on screen

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open + name of the directory"
```

I thought thay maybe it was because of an import of other file of the footer.js file, but I have checked and the routes have been automatically updated. So, any idea about how could I fix it? Thanks, regards.

Answer (score 2):

Search-all through your project directory for just "footer" - something is probably importing it that you haven't spotted.